# Why is Java 6 compiled class size larger than Java 5?

Tags: java, class, bytecode, javac

We are noticing that when we compile our classes on Java 6, they are consistently larger than Java 5.

I understand that there has not been a change to the byte code to date, so I assume the Java 6 compiler is throwing in more stuff. Is that all required, or is there any way to turn that off and still compile Java 6 source code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version 6 javac is generating additional "Stack Map" attributes in the class files to make verification by the jvm easier and faster. I doubt this amounts too much size difference, you could alway use the `-target 1.5` option to make it generate the same bytecode as earlier in versions.

**Edit:** Details on this new attribute can be found in section 4.8.4 of [jsr 202](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr202/index.html)

> 4.8.4 The StackMapTable Attribute
>
> The stack map attribute is a variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a Code
>   attribute. The name of the attribute is StackMapTable. This attribute is used during
>   the process of verification by typechecking (§4.11.1).
>
> A stack map attribute consists of zero or more stack map frames. Each stack map
>   frame specifies (either explicitly or implicitly) a bytecode offset, the verification
>   types (§4.11.1) for the local variables, and the verification types for the operand
>   stack.

Comment: Is this the only added part for v6 javac?

Comment: I guess it's probably the main reason why JDK 1.5 cannot run version 1.6's code except for those new classes and new features.

Answer (score 2):

Dump the contents of the files with the `javap` command to see if anything obvious stands out. There might be some extra attributes in Java 6 class files.